# Merge return types of interface containing functions

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript-types

Let's say we have an object containing some functions:

```
const handlers = {
  handler1: (state: State, payload: boolean) => ({
    schema: payload,
    errors: [],
  }),
  handler2: (state: State, payload: string[]) => ({
    errors: payload,
  }),
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
  reset: (...args: any) => initialState,
}
```

I need to define a type that merges their return types like

```
State | {
  schema: boolean,
  errors: never[]
} | {
  errors: string[]
}
```

One simple solution could be

```
type MergeReturnTypes1 = ReturnType<typeof handlers[keyof typeof handlers]>
```

However I'm not getting why the following type definition

```
type MergeReturnType2<H> = H extends Record<string, (...args: any) => infer T> ? T : never
```

Is only return the return type of the first function contained in the `handlers` object

```
type T = MergeReturnType2<typeof handlers>

T = {
  schema: boolean
  errors: never[]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am honestly not sure why this is not working but I'm still trying to figure out an explanation.

You can fix the problem by using `T` to infer the whole function in the `Record` instead of only inferring the return type.

```
type MergeReturnType2<H> = H extends Record<string, infer T extends (...args: any) => any> 
  ? ReturnType<T> 
  : never

type T = MergeReturnType2<typeof handlers>

// type T = State | {
//     schema: boolean;
//     errors: never[];
// } | {
//     errors: string[];
// }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAyiAhiWBeGBvGiBcMDOIATgJYB2A5jAL7DADGA9mYTOSSCYgDYLJqZq2fPCQo6TFiBgALRGQAm3KERHoMwGLPlKVARjwAKQvzx8UAGhgREYbo0QK8AI0aNl8gJQxUAPhiGGlpa%20PQyUAC2uNa29o4WmsEqRIyqeADaALoJWtSeOdqKykQATEYmKGZiUFY2dg5OBMTkFFnefgFBSUQpaTH18Yl5BQD0IzBQ%20NzkIAC0CiT4iM7Ks2RQAB5z0%20swAALg0KGkEHOTOyAjZIyzAK5kt-hQCrMAboiqiUSTUCBGAHSAj4UfB4eRgdr%20dicHjmGrAWigSCwACyKgoUAASr9bkQyAAVZH4PQ%20GDYkC4gnIgA8hygjAAZoVdKp0gBrKBgRkwOncuRFFT4TK%20OhI6AwNFEDHkymE6AlakACX86EVEy2UEUImxTCICmphFIlCs5AZKhg%20PVKC1AUB-2BoOwZAhPn84P8iQA-GScXi5VBqfiPVo8OtXio6HSLaTJdLfVT5bTkXydMV8CLgGMecjo%20g4TAAD6YTPjYIEMKRaKudxQeQAbhLZYmPVSjrDKiyDazQiLGizZeSrbwhpancb1CAA)

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGxoF4oG8CwAoKuoDMBLCAGwBMBGALigGdgAnQgOwHNs8DjyAmGgIwD2gkhHjMOeWgGMAFhAC28GuJAAaSbggMGghrRr0mbANoBdbAF9s2aYOb0oLQsELwScRCnSaupSjQA5IEaOHhE-nwE7rQQVlDwtLAISDZYdg7AULLiZKL6UKiYYTnMedrUUAAU9F40nkhqUGDwICSC8GQqzCAAlIUAfNXFnDLySjQtbR1koZzauvo05nNQlr2rpeUMUTUpEPX7TVPtnYaMLKzm-chDVSN4C3oGza2ns5LrqwD031AQtBILGAAFoyIRaPB+KIQcwIAAPUFAuFQAACoEgMiYYFBAORwG+zEEIIArswSbEyCCAG7wfSSBgAiDAGhVAB0HLprBeqhuQ2crncDQgoWsWGwGOgAFltKwIAAlZkkhjMAAq4AgAB4ABJDVDa-6IiBlJKKuwMMiaoyXJrszkMbndPqDJzMfDaKCqoYAfk9UBocOp2jSkqg2ty+SSqElgnw2Qj2loIY1ftQModCqVKvVkB1Cf0AyAA

Comment: Look at the example above, it doesn't make sense